# After VBA function runs, #N/A in cells

Tags: vba, excel

The code below functions properly: it pastes a range of cells from Sheet "GP Data" to "RAW". The first section of the code copies a range of 3x3, and the latter code copies a range of 4x4.

The earlier code executes with no error value, as shown in the image below.

However the latter code performs the required function, but always produces cells with `#N/A` in the next column, after the data has been pasted.

```
arrData = Sheets("GP Data").Range("U12:U14").Value
Set rngwrite = Nothing
Set rngwrite = Sheets("DZ").Range("A:A").Find(strdate, LookIn:=xlFormulas)
Do While rngwrite Is Nothing
    With Sheets("DZ").Range("A60000")
        .End(xlUp).AutoFill (.End(xlUp).Resize(2))
    End With
    Set rngwrite = Sheets("DZ").Range("A:A").Find(CDate(strdate),        LookIn:=xlFormulas)
Loop
rngwrite.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 3).Value = Application.Transpose(arrData)

arrData = Sheets("GP Data").Range("P12:R14").Value
'find get the first non-blank column in row 7 from right to left
Set rngwrite = Sheets("RAW").Range("IV7").End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1)
'paste data
rngwrite.Resize(3, 3).Value = arrData
'drag dates across row 7
rngwrite.Offset(-1).Value = rngwrite.Offset(-1, -3).Value + 1
```

[image]

```
arrData = Sheets("GP Data").Range("U12:U15").Value
Set rngwrite = Nothing
Set rngwrite = Sheets("DZ").Range("A:A").Find(strdate, LookIn:=xlFormulas)
Do While rngwrite Is Nothing
    With Sheets("DZ").Range("A60000")
        .End(xlUp).AutoFill (.End(xlUp).Resize(2))
    End With
    Set rngwrite = Sheets("DZ").Range("A:A").Find(CDate(strdate), LookIn:=xlFormulas)
Loop
rngwrite.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 4).Value = Application.Transpose(arrData)

arrData = Sheets("GP Data").Range("P12:R15").Value
'find get the first non-blank column in row 7 from right to left
Set rngwrite = Sheets("RAW").Range("IV7").End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1)
'paste data
rngwrite.Resize(4, 4).Value = arrData
'drag dates across row 7
rngwrite.Offset(-1).Value = rngwrite.Offset(-1, -3).Value + 1
```

Comment: Your second data set is only **3** columns (P, Q and R).

Comment: @Rory What do you mean by (P, Q and R)? The cells copied are from GP Data field range P12:R15 which is the 4x4 range cells.

Comment: No that's 4x3. Count the number of columns...

Comment: Oh yeah, silly mistake. Thanks for bringing it up.